# When i change something in my object, my value in interpolation is not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this `v-for`:

```
<tr v-for="(product, index) in products" v-bind:key="products.id">
   <div v-on:click="decrementQtd(index)" class="action-qtd-button-left">
       <strong>-</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="div-input-qtd">
       <input v-model="product.quantity" class="input-qtd-cart" type="text">
   </div>
</tr>
```

And in my **script**:

```
methods: {
   decrementQtd: function (index) {
      this.products[index].quantity--
}
```

If i do a `console.log(quantity)` is decrementing ok, but the value in interpolation is not updating, how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Pen based on this code and it is working fine. Clicking the - is reducing quantity in text box. Please check here:
https://codepen.io/v08i/pen/KKwOgaw

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
<tr v-for="(product, index) in products" v-bind:key="product.id">
   <td><div v-on:click="decrementQtd(index)" class="action-qtd-button-left">
       <strong>-</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="div-input-qtd">
       <input v-model="product.quantity" class="input-qtd-cart" type="text">
   </div>
    </td>
</tr>
  </table>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Jonathan',
    products: [
      {
      id: 1,
      quantity: 10
      },
      {
      id: 2,
      quantity: 15
      },
      {
      id: 3,
      quantity: 25
      }
    ]
  },
  methods:{
     decrementQtd: function (index) {
      this.products[index].quantity--
}
  }
})
```

Note: I have also added td inside tr, if you remove them, code stops working.

Comment: yeah, seems that not have difference between this code and my, but i also don't have the new values.. i will investigate more

Comment: Can you try ```this.$forceUpdate()``` after you are reducing the quantiy in method?

Comment: working now. You know why i have to do this? This could be a bad practice?

Comment: There might be something else in your code that is breaking reactivity? Which version of vue are you using.?

Comment: i'm using "vue": "^2.6.11"